# Prove $\| v+iTv\|=\| v-iTv\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

$ִT : V \to V $ such that $T^*=T$ , $V$ is an inner product space.

Prove $\| v+iTv\|=\| v-iTv\|$

My try :

I tried to show $\| v+iTv\|^2=\| v-iTv\|^2 \implies | v+iTv\|=\| v-iTv\|$

$$\| v+iTv\|^2=$$
$$\langle v+iTv ,v+iTv\rangle=$$

$$\langle v,v\rangle-i\langle Tv,v \rangle+i \langle Tv,v \rangle+\langle iTv,iTv \rangle =$$

$$\langle v,v\rangle-i\langle Tv,v \rangle+i \langle Tv,v \rangle+\langle Tv,Tv \rangle =$$

$$\langle v-iTv  ,v\rangle +i \langle Tv,v \rangle+\langle Tv,Tv \rangle =$$

Here I get stuck

Help is welcome.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go from one expression to the other, just that the two can be brought to the same form. Your steps are correct:
\begin{align}
\|v+iTv\|^2
&=\langle v+iTv,v+iTv\rangle \\
&=\langle v,v\rangle-i\langle Tv,v\rangle+i\langle v,Tv\rangle+\langle Tv,Tv\rangle
\end{align}
Now you can observe that
$$
i\langle v,Tv\rangle=i\langle T^*v,v\rangle=i\langle Tv,v\rangle
$$
because by assumption $T$ is self-adjoint, and so you get
$$
\|v+iTv\|^2=\langle v,v\rangle+\langle Tv,Tv\rangle
$$
If you replace $i$ with $-i$ you get the same.